# Does GridSearchCV call initialisers of the objects in pipeline?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I wrote a code to process Kaggle's Titanic Data. The class that I wrote is as follows:

```
class Transform(BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin):  

   def __init__(self,select_dict={},default=False,list_of_attributes=dataset_columns,
             one_hot_default=True,one_hot={}):
       if list_of_attributes is None:
            list_of_attributes=dataset_columns
       self.attributes=select_dict #Here I select which attributes to take
       self.Transformed=[]
       #if default is False(True) it changes all other attributes to
       #default that I do not select (to make things a little easy
   def transform_Name(self,X):
       #Transformation function for specific attribute
       #I made such functions for every attribute and then they append
       #The transformed series in self.Transformed
       self.Transformed.append(X); 

   def transform(self,X,y=None):
       #This function calls transform function of whose value is True in 
       #self.attributes and finally returns the DataFrame
       return pd.concat(self.Transformed_Data,axis=1)
```

I have only show relevant code of this class.
Now, I create a pipeline using SVC class of SKlearn

```
transfomer=Transform(select_dict={'PassengerId': False},default=True)
svc_grid_clf=Pipeline([
('transform',transformer),
('SVC',SVC())
])
```

Once I create this pipeline I create a GridSearchCV using the following parameter grid

```
Param=[
{
'SVC__kernel': ['rbf'],
'SVC__C': [0.1,1,1.5]
}]
```

Now creating GridSearchCV object

```
grid_svm=GridSearchCV(estimator=svc_grid_clf,cv=3,param_grid=Param)
#Now fitting
grid_svm.fit(X,y)
```

However, I receive some error that I am not able to understand i.e.

> ValueError: No objects to concatenate.

I believe the error is because the GridSearchCV is either calling or not calling the **init** function of Transformer, thus sometimes the select_dict of Transformer is not coming as it should be.

Comment: ('SVC',SVC()) - may be it's redundant parentheses? try ('SVC',SVC)
And where you instantiate SVC like you do it with Transform?

Comment: From where does the `self.Transformed_Data` fill up? And also post the complete stack trace of error.

Comment: @CrazyElf I have tried what you said removing the '()' from SVC() but then it is not able to call it's __init__ since it's just an alias for the class SVC.

Comment: @VivekKumar I have edited the question details as required. The self.Transformed_Data is filled by functions like self.transform_Name()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sklearn API requires that you pass estimator instances everywhere, not estimatoe classes. When you create a sklearn-compatible estimator, you just create an object which holds parameters (but not the data). Actual work should be performed in fit/transform/... methods.

It seems your Transformer class doesn't follow these API ideas. You shouldn't store passed data as attributes of the class; Transformer.transform method should work on the passed X matrix, not on self.Transformed_Data attribute. There is an [example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-hetero-feature-union-py) on how to write such transformers.

Comment: So, this means that I should not store the data in the class. Thanks @Mikhail Korobov